# Elasticsearch query returning false results when term exceeds ngram length

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-5, n-gram

The requirement is to search partial phrases in a block of text. Most of the words will be standard length. I want to keep the max_gram value down to 10. But there may be the occasional id/code with more characters than that, and these show up if I type in a query where the first 10 characters match, but then the rest don't.

For example, here is the mapping:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and document:

```
POST my_index/doc/1
{
  "title": "Quick fox with id of ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" 
}
```

If I run the query:

```
POST my_index/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": {
        "query": "fox wi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns the document as expected. However, if I run this:

```
POST my_index/doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": {
        "query": "ABCDEFGHIJxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It also returns the document, when it shouldn't. It will do this if the x's are after the 10th character, but not before it. How can I avoid this?

I am using version 5.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the analyzer that is used at index time is the same analyzer that is used at search time, meaning the edge_ngram analyzer is used on your search term. This is not what you want. You will end up with 10 tokens as the search terms, none of which contain those last 3 characters.

You will want to take a look at the [Search Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-analyzer.html) for your mapping. This documentation points out this specific use case:

> Sometimes, though, it can make sense to use a different analyzer at search time, such as when using the edge_ngram tokenizer for autocomplete.

The standard analyzer may suit your needs:

```
{
...
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```